# Creating a user-defined function with conditions on input (x,y) in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a function which takes input (x,y). The function is for the four sides of square x=0,  x=1 and y = 0, y=1
The function value is zero on three sides and =k on the fourth side. I create this code for the function:

```
function f = func_bc(x,y)
if x==0 && y>=0
    f = 0;
elseif y==0 && x>=0
    f = 0;
elseif y==1 && x>=0
    f = 0;
elseif x==1 && y>0
    f = k;
end
end
```

However this does not work when I give a vector as input using feval:
         x = meshgrid(0:0.01:1);
         y = meshgrid(0:0.01:1);
         a = feval(func_bc,x(2:101,1),y(2:101,1));

The error is:
    Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

How do I create such a function?

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `&` and `|` instead of `&&` and `||`. The double operators would be used if `x` and `y` were single scalar values. The single operators must be used when either side of the relation is a vector, as in your case.

Comment: Thanks David, part of the problem is solved but when constant values are assigned to a f which is the case here, it does not create a vector of output values. I resolved this problem by writing f = 0 as f = x-x ; Is there a formal way to solve this problem?

Comment: You could really make the code into two lines. First `f=zeros(size(x));` Followed by `f(x==1 & y>0) = k;`

Answer (score 1):

replace && with &.

Comment: Thanks a lot, part of the problem is solved but when constant values are assigned to a f which is the case here, it does not create a vector of output values. I resolved this problem by writing f = 0 as f = x-x ; Is there a formal way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you need?

```
function z = mysquare(x,y)
k = 10;
z = zeros(size(x));
z(x==1 & y>0) = k;

>> [X,Y] = meshgrid(0:0.1:1, 0:0.1:1);
>> Z = mysquare(X,Y);
```